Unable to populate data using useList with GraphQL in Refine - data remains undefined
I'm working on a React application using the Refine framework along with GraphQL. I'm trying to insert mock data into a component using the useList hook. The mock data should be fetched from a GraphQL resource (dealStages) that I learned about in a recent YouTube tutorial.
However, I'm encountering an issue where the data variable remains undefined, and I'm unable to retrieve any data. Below is the relevant part of my code:
import { DASHBOARD_DEALS_CHART_QUERY } from '@/graphql/queries';
import { mapDealsData } from '@/utilities/helpers';
import { Area, AreaConfig } from '@ant-design/plots';
import { useList, HttpError } from "@refinedev/core";
import React from 'react';

const DealsChart = () => {
  // Use the useList from refine that enables fetching data from our API:
  const { data } = useList({
    resource: 'dealStages',
    meta: {
      gqlQuery: DASHBOARD_DEALS_CHART_QUERY,
    },
  });

  console.log(data);

  const config: AreaConfig = {
    data: [],
  };

  const dealData = React.useMemo(() => {
    return mapDealsData(data?.data);
  }, [data?.data]);

  // Rest of the component...
};


And here's the DASHBOARD_DEALS_CHART_QUERY:
export const DASHBOARD_DEALS_CHART_QUERY = gql`
  query DashboardDealsChart(
    $filter: DealStageFilter!
    $sorting: [DealStageSort!]
    $paging: OffsetPaging
  ) {
    dealStages(filter: $filter, sorting: $sorting, paging: $paging) {
      nodes {
        id
        title
        dealsAggregate {
          groupBy {
            closeDateMonth
            closeDateYear
          }
          sum {
            value
          }
        }
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
`;


Issue:
The data variable remains undefined when I log it, which means that my component doesn't receive any data to work with.
Questions:
Is there something I'm missing in the way I'm using useList with GraphQL in Refine?
Could there be an issue with the GraphQL query, or should I be passing additional parameters to the useList hook?
What could be the reason for the data not being fetched properly, and how can I resolve it?
If there's any other information that might be helpful, please let me know. Thanks in advance for your assistance!
